# Reduce loop time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Loops in python taking alot time to give result.This contains around 100k records.

It is taking lot of time. How time can be reduced

```
df['loan_agr'] = df['loan_agr'].astype(int)

for i in range(len(df)):

    if df.loc[i,'order_mt']== df.loc[i,'enr_mt']:

        df['new_N_Loan'] = 1

        df['exist_N_Loan'] = 0

        df['new_V_Loan'] = df['loan_agr']

        df['exist_V_Loan'] = 0

    else:        

        df['new_N_Loan'] = 0

        df['exist_N_Loan'] = 1

        df['new_V_Loan'] = 0

        df['exist_V_Loan'] = df['loan_agr']
```

Comment: can you post a short slice of input dataframe?

Comment: Can someone improve the question by mentioning what library this is about? And maybe add a tag as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `loc` and set the new values in a vectorized way. This approach is much faster than using iteration because these operations are performed on entire columns at once, rather than individual values. Check out [this article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) for more on speed optimization in pandas.

For example:

```
mask = df['order_mt'] == df['enr_mt']
df.loc[mask, ['new_N_Loan', 'exist_N_Loan', 'exist_V_Loan']] = [1, 0, 0]
df.loc[mask, ['new_V_Loan']] = df['loan_agr']

df.loc[~mask, ['new_N_Loan', 'exist_N_Loan', 'new_V_Loan']] = [0, 1, 0]
df.loc[~mask, ['exist_V_Loan']] = df['loan_agr']
```

**Edit:**

If the `~` (bitwise not) operator is not supported in your version of pandas, you can make a new mask for the "else" condition, similar to the first condition.

For example:

```
mask = df['order_mt'] == df['enr_mt']
else_mask = df['order_mt'] != df['enr_mt']
```

Then use the `else_mask` for the second set of definitions instead of `~mask`.

**Sample:**

Input:

```
   order_mt  enr_mt new_N_Loan exist_N_Loan exist_V_Loan new_V_Loan  loan_agr
0         1       1       None         None         None       None       100
1         2       2       None         None         None       None       200
2         3      30       None         None         None       None       300
3         4      40       None         None         None       None       400
```

Output:

```
   order_mt  enr_mt  new_N_Loan  exist_N_Loan  exist_V_Loan  new_V_Loan  loan_agr
0         1       1           1             0             0         100       100
1         2       2           1             0             0         200       200
2         3      30           0             1           300           0       300
3         4      40           0             1           400           0       400
```

Comment: One of the most helpful answers I've seen on stack recently, thanks for sharing @Henry and the link had even more good tricks.

I do have a question though, do you have any idea what is so different about this mask approach; what I mean to ask is, wouldn't it internally be iterating only, so how come this is faster than a usual pythonic loop? Is this also related to the integration of C with Python in the background? 

Any idea?

Comment: Hi Henry, Thanks for the response. ~ does not works there as  i am working on order version of pandas on server. Also i could not update pandas lib.

Comment: @AmitAmola it is faster because `loc` can use a  boolean array for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). `loc` does not "loop" through the dataframe it returns a view of the dataframe based on location based indexing.

Comment: @yashul I see, I've updated my answer, let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks @Henry.I tried to execute both the codes one written by me second one you just shared on sample data of 100 records. However my code took 12 seconds, your code took 25 seconds. I am not sure if there could be another way to optimize the snippet.

Comment: @yashul I would see how they performs on 1000 records. Your solution should take about 10x as long for 1000 records, and because of the vectorization, this solution should take roughly the same amount of time. That's often the case for parallelized solutions is that they underperform iteration on small cases but as the input size grows they perform relatively better than iteration.

Comment: Hi Henry, Thank you so much. It is super super fast. Previously i was using if loop as well with your snippet. this method rocked :).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of range(Len(...)) you could change the len function to a value.

Comment: Comment on this answer if you need a different answer